# Why does ssh log me in as the wrong user?

Tags: mac, remote-control, ssh, command-line

I am shelling into my Mac (ssh) and get logged in with the wrong userid. There are three unprivileged user accounts on the system, and when I log in, I give my password, and whoami gives me either of the other unprivileged user accounts. (And I can't write to files I own, etc.)

I can workaround to access my account by su [*my username*], but I'm puzzled. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ssh` can get confused if your short name is different between the two machines. You can check what your short name is on each machine with `whoami`. To go to a particular account, use `ssh jhayward@mymac`. If you still have trouble, use `ssh -v jhayward@mymac`. You may see things like checking `~/.ssh/config`. If you want to avoid typing `jhaward@` all of the time, you can make (or add to) the file `~/.ssh/config` with the lines

```
Host mymac
Hostname 1234.1234.1234
User jhaward
```

editing each line for your particular case (the `Host` is your nickname, the `Hostname` is the IP address, or mymac.local or whatever you currently use for `ssh`).

Then you can just use `ssh mymac`.

If you still have trouble, post some output from `ssh -v` but be careful to not post anything private (like IP addresses).